# Problem accessing an array element from json in angular/html

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, mongodb

I have the following json data, which comes from mongoDB:

```
{"list":
  [{
    "_id":"62f2fabd09de07c09f9e17e2",
    "categoryName":"Web development",
    "subcategories":[
      {
        "subcategoryName":"Backend",
        "skills":["Nodejs", "Express"]
      },
      {
        "subcategoryName":"Frontend",
        "skills":["Css", "SASS"]
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "_id":"62f33ba62ae52a71daa99a30",
    "categoryName":"Cybersecurity",
    "subcategories":[
      {
        "subcategoryName":"Red team",
        "skills":["cURL","wfuzz"]
      },
      {
        "subcategoryName":"Blue team",
        "skills":["Cloudfare", "Burpsuite"]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

This is my angular scope, which gets the json data from the endpoint:

```
$scope.listSkills = function() {
    $http.get("/showSkills").success(function(skills_from_database){
        $scope.skills = skills_from_database.list;
    })
}
```

And finally is my html/angular code

```
<div ng-repeat="category in skills">
  <h1>{{category.categoryName}}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">
    <hr>
    <h2>{{subcategory.subcategoryName}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="skill in category.subcategories">
      <h5>{{skill.skills}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is:
Category works

Subcategory works, but it gets all skills from the category, not only from the subcategory

Skills doesn't work, it gets the skills section but it should get all the arrays value, which I don't know how to do

[image: Final result]
[image: Json data]

Comment: Why are you nesting two `ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">`? and ng-repeat="skill in category.subcategories"

Comment: It doesn't show the skills if I dont do it like that

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311414/227299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop needs to iterate over each member of `subcategory.skills` . I'm not sure why you are iterating again over the same object. (`ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories"` and `ng-repeat="skill in category.subcategories"`)

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in subcategory.skills">
{skill}
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed everything, thanks, now the subcat have only the corresponding skills and the skills are shown without the array syntax ["skill"]