# Problem binding 2 selects with angularjs and json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller:

```
app.controller("AllController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.listSkills = function() {
        $http.get("/showSkills").success(function(skills_from_database){
            $scope.skills = skills_from_database.list;
        })
    }
});
```

This is the html with both selects, but only the first one works:

```
<select name="skill_category" id="skill_category" form="AddSkillForm" onclick="showNewCatInput()">
  <option value="newCat">New category</option>
  <option ng-repeat="category in skills" value="{{category.categoryName}}">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
</select>


<select name="skill_subcategory" id="skill_subcategory" form="AddSkillForm" onclick="showNewSubCatInput()">
  <option value="newSubCat">New subcategory</option>
  <option ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories" value="{{subcategory.subcategoryName}}">{{subcategory.subcategoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

So I know that to get all the subcategories I need the category selected on the first select, but I don't know how to do it. As I read, I think that I need to use ng-model, but even if I could connect the 2 selects, it would still not work the second one.

That is because I can't access the subcategory with this:

```
ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories"
```

Simply because "category" doesn't exist there, so where it comes? from this other code that works:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in skills">
  <h1>{{category.categoryName}}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">
    <h2>{{subcategory.subcategoryName}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I know I have to access to "category in skills" first, but what I need is not all categories in skills, I need just the selected category.

So to summarize the problems:

Don't know how to use ng-model to bind 2 selects and
don't know how to access the subcategories from the selected category

The json data and angular scope can be found in this other post that I made yesterday, there you can also see the html/angular code that works to get the category and subcategory.
[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311302/problem-accessing-an-array-element-from-json-in-angular-html)

Comment: After your first select box, I guess this showNewCatInput() code needs to generate a new dataset, based on what subcategories are available. So you create a local array of this.subCategories that gets updated each time showNewCatInput() is fired.

Comment: That's the first thing I try, but can't get the subcategories array based on the category selected, I can get the `selectedIndex` value but I don't know how to do something with it. `var category = document.getElementById("skill_category").selectedIndex;`

Comment: On the first input ```value="{{category}}"```

Comment: I will assume that you mean first option. The first select that shows the categories works, but for the second to work I need to use: `ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories"`, but I don't know how to replace the `category.subcategories` with my variable category that has the index value. I explain in the post why `category.subcategories`  doesn't work

Comment: You will need to share your controller code, I don't think you fully understand how the template reads and gets its data-bindings from the controller.

Comment: Here is the controller: https://pastebin.com/BTA34a3F

Comment: You have only exposed $scope.skills you need to define $scope.categories and then update this each time you update "AddSkillForm" this is angularjs not angular, so I have updated your original post. AngularJS has now reached end of life and I would discourage learning/developing it unless you have legacy requirements.

Comment: I didn't even know that there were 2 angulars, this is just a personal project to learn angular as well as mongoDB. I will research if I can change from angularjs to angular. Anyways, the `$scope.skills` is a list of the data from mongoDB, which means that `categories` is in `skills.categories`. At the end of the post is a link to a question I did before, it contains the scope and database schema